# onLocationChanged Stops when phone screen is off in android here is my on location changed function

Tags: android, gps, location

Here is my code example in the end of this function i add the longitude and latitude in array the app is adding the latitude and longitude in array but when screen is off then doesn't

````
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        String msg = "Updated Location: " +
                Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
                Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String Latitude = String.valueOf((new DecimalFormat("##.#######").format(location.getLatitude())));
        String Longitude = String.valueOf((new DecimalFormat("##.#######").format(location.getLongitude())));
        locationLatitudeArrayList.add(Latitude);
        locationLongitudeArrayList.add(Longitude);


    } ```
````

Comment: post full code here

Comment: Are you removing the listener in any of the Activity lifecycle callbacks? like onPause or onStop?

Comment: No i am not removing the listener

Comment: In newer Android versions (not sure, when it starts), you can give the following location permissions: "Allow all the time", "Allow only while using the app" and "Deny". Please check in the app permissions, whether you allowed "all the time".